# Generate percentage metrics between two queries

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, group-by, count

How to generate percentage metrics between two queries on the same table with different conditions ?

**Example:**

```
_________________________________________
            |        |         |
environment | online | offline | metrics
____________|________|_________|_________

  web          3         1         75%
  docker       2         1         50%
```

**Query 1:**

```
Select environment, count(available) from tb_infra where available = 'ON' group by environment order by count desc
```

**Query 2:**

```
Select environment, count(available) from tb_infra where available = 'OFF' group by environment order by count desc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation. The standard `filter` clause to aggregate functions, which Postgres supports, comes handy for this:

```
select
    environment,
    count(*) filter(where available = 'ON')  online,
    count(*) filter(where available = 'OFF') offline,
    avg((available = 'ON')::int) metrics
from tb_infra 
group by environment
```

In this resultset, `metrics` is a value between `0` and `1` that represents the ratio of `'ON'` records. You can easily turn that to a percentage by multiplying it by `100`.

Comment: Simply excellent, thank you very much for the explanation and help!

Comment: A doubt, what would it look like instead of 0.75, showing 75.30?